# how to declare multiple arrays in iframe and set timer for arrays

Tags: javascript, cognos

I need help in the javascript,

I need display 3 set of cognos reports on the TV screen at particular intervals of time.

1 set of cognos reports need to be started at 00 hrs in the midnight and need to be displayed till 07:00 hrs in the morning and 2 set should start at 07:00 hrs till evening 19:00 hrs and the last set of reports should start at 19:00 till 00:00 hrs

All this set of reports get refreshed every 10 mins and need to display fresh data for every 10 mins.

ex: in a set of reports there are 12 individual reports which displays for 30 sec on the tv screen and it will run in a loop.

Please can anybody help me with how to declare multiple arrays in iframe and set timmer to the array.

Let me know if you need any more information

example code for single array

```
<html> 
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var slideimages = new Array();
            slideimages[0] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%201ST%20PAGE%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%201ST%20PAGE&run.outputFormat=&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[1] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20FULL%20CASE%20PICKER%20SHIFT%201%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20FULL%20CASE%20PICKER%20SHIFT%201&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[2] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20FULL%20CASE%20PICKER%20SHIFT%202%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20FULL%20CASE%20PICKER%20SHIFT%202&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[3] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20INDIRECT%20SHIFT%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20INDIRECT%20SHIFT&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[4] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LATE%20PICKS%20SCOREBOARD%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LATE%20PICKS%20SCOREBOARD&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[5] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REMAINING%20CASES%20TO%20PICK%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REMAINING%20CASES%20TO%20PICK&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[6] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REMAINING%20LETDOWNS%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REMAINING%20LETDOWNS&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[7] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REPICKS%20PENDING%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20LOCAL%20ROUTES%20REPICKS%20PENDING&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[8] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20MEZZANINE%20SHIFT%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20MEZZANINE%20SHIFT&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[9] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20SECTION%20AND%20REPORT%20GROUP%20SUMMARY%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20SECTION%20AND%20REPORT%20GROUP%20SUMMARY&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";
            slideimages[10] = "http://COGDEVWEB1:80/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=CAMID(%22dcanalyze%3au%3aa202da3d8b73bb4b954d583834a025a5%22)%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27My%20Folders%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27Anil%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27On%20Screen%20Testing%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20SCHEDULES%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27ON%20SCREEN%20DISPLAYS%27%5d%2ffolder%5b%40name%3d%27SCOREBOARD%20SCHEDULES%2007%3a00%20-%2019%3a00%27%5d%2freport%5b%40name%3d%27BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20TOWER%20SHIFT%27%5d&ui.name=BRACKENFELL%20DC%20-%20TOWER%20SHIFT&run.outputFormat=HTML&run.prompt=true";

// style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" frameborder="0" 
// style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"
    </script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">        

        body
        {
            margin:   0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #iframe1
        {
            height:   100%;
            left:     0px;
            position: absolute;
            top:      0px;
            width:    100%;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <iframe id="slide" src="" frameborder="0" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;" height="100%" width="100%" ></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var step=0
        function slideit(){
         document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step]
         if (step<slideimages.length-1)
         step++
         else
          step=0
         setTimeout("slideit()",20000)
        }
        slideit()

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You should not call `setTimeout` passing it a string. That is the same as using `eval` and that should be avoided, says so in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). Pass `setTimeout` your function directly. So: `setTimeout(slideit,20000);` Also what is wrong with your implementation? Finally its usually preferred to use the `[]` notation to declare an array instead of the `new Array()` wrapper.

Comment: Is it possible for us to show or display a set of reports in iframe at a given time    i.e  from morning 7 am to evening 7 am it has to show a set reports in iframe,  can you please send me the code. as i am a cognos developer and unable to crack the code for the timer in javascript.